# redbeanphp hide properties by default

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I'm using amazing orm "RedbeanPhp" from http://redbeanphp.com/, I like how it speeds up the development so much, but the documentation is a bit outdated.

1. How can I select a few properties when using `R::findAll()`?

For example I only want to select id, email from users, this will grap all the users columns, but I only need 2 columns.

2. Is it possible to hide certain columns by default inside bean? "hide password inside users for example"?

To solve this I currently use a bit verbose code:

```
$users = R::findAll('users')->export();
foreach($users as $user){
 unset($user->password, $user->token);//...etc
}
print_r($users);
```

But it would be nice if could set this inside a fuse model or something?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getAll($sql_query)` instead `findAll()`

...in your example

`$users= R::getAll('select id,email from users')'`

More info about querying with RedBeanPHP [here](https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/queries)

Only "con": `$users` is not an array of beans, just an array of associative array, having colnames as indexes.

If not enough for you, you can use function `convertToBeans(...)` as detailed in the link included before